# TypeError: dst is not a numpy array, neither a scalar - resize jpg python

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to resize an image for further perspective treatments and I'm getting this error.

```
File "/home/passerin/Documents/tesis/Project/test/scanner2/scan2.py", line 79, in resize
resized = cv2.resize(img, (height, width), interpolation)
TypeError: dst is not a numpy array, neither a scalar
```

here's the code...

```
# load an image
flat_object=cv2.imread("/home/passerin/Documents/tesis/Project/test/scanner2/images/personal-foto-5.png")
# resize the image
flat_object_resized = resize(flat_object, height=600)
# make a copy
flat_object_resized_copy = flat_object.copy()
#convert to HSV color scheme
flat_object_resized_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(flat_object_resized_copy, 
cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
# split HSV to three chanels
hue, saturation, value = cv2.split(flat_object_resized_hsv)
```

this is where the error shows up.

```
def resize(img, width=None, height=None, interpolation=cv2.INTER_AREA):
    global ratio
    w, h, _ = img.shape

    if width is None and height is None:
        return img
    elif width is None:
        ratio = height / h
        width = int(w * ratio)
        # print(width)
        resized = cv2.resize(img, (height, width), interpolation)
        return resized
    else:
        ratio = width / w
        height = int(h * ratio)
        # print(height)
        resized = cv2.resize(img, (height, width), interpolation)
        return resized
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You  are calling with positional arguments but according to the [argument specifcation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#resize) you left some out - it thinks your third positional argument is for the `dst` parameter.  Even though parameters/arguments are optional if you don't *supply* them with their keyword, the function expects them in the order given in the argspec.  Try calling it with keyword arguments

```
cv2.resize(src = img, dsize = (height, width), interpolation = interpolation)
```

or just

```
cv2.resize(img, (height, width), interpolation = interpolation)
```

Comment: Tyvm for the answer wwii, it worked like a charm! I'm new to python so this kind of things tend to happen D: